# Is 'similarly' okay in this sentence? On my matura exam only 'similar' was accepted. I think that both are correct

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

Several governments have now begun treating the selfie as a serious threat to public
safety, leading them to launch public education campaigns (21) ________ to those
against smoking and binge drinking.

Comment: No.  Only "similar" is acceptable.

Comment: If you use _similarly_, you are saying that the campaigns against smoking and drinking had previously launched campaigns against selfies, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Only "**similar**" is correct.

"Similarly" would be the adverb form, meaning that it describes an action, while "similar" is the adjective form, which describes a noun.

In this case, **"similar"** describes the *public education campaigns,* which means only the adjective usage is correct.

Comment: Similarly could refer to 'launch' in my opinion.

Comment: "Similarly" couldn't refer to "launch" because the statement is "... to launch public education campaigns similar **to those** against smoking..." The use of *those* is very important because it implies that the education campaigns are similar to the smoking campaigns, not to the launching of the campaigns. If the statement was "to launch public education campaigns **similarly** to **the launching** of smoking campaigns..." then I would agree with you.

Comment: I think it means the same even if the word 'launching' is not there

Comment: they launch the public education campaigns similarly to the (launching of) smoking campaigns

Comment: That usage is correct. However, it would be incorrect to refer to "the launching of" as "those" because "the launching of" is not plural.